# How to do an API call in ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I want to make an API call where the response is in XML format.

This is the API description: http://www.dictionaryapi.com/products/api-collegiate-dictionary.htm

I have registered and I have a key to use in the request URL.

Could anyone give me an idea of how to make the call and analyse the response?

Thankyou.

Comment: you should do some research and then post your question.

Comment: here's a reference for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/hypocrite?key=1234");
var response = request.GetResponse();    
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Then you can grab what you need like:

```
xdoc.Element("ElementName");
```